# gdb taking the executable in the wrong directory?

Tags: debugging, gdb

I can't figure out what the issue is here. I am in a directory:

```
pwd
```

> /afs/naf.desy.de/user/e/eron/scratch/UserCode/**devRA4b**/UserCode/DesySusy/ra4b_2012

where I have an executable called myAnalysis. However, I also have another directory called

> /afs/naf.desy.de/user/e/eron/scratch/UserCode/**RA4bHead**/UserCode/DesySusy/ra4b_2012/

I am now in the **first** one, and if I do:

```
gdb myAnalysis
```

I get:
`

> Reading symbols from `/afs/naf.desy.de/user/e/eron/scratch/UserCode/**RA4bHead**/UserCode/DesySusy/ra4b_2012/myAnalysis...done.

why does it take the executable from the wrong directory and how can I solve that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could it be that the second path is specified within your `PATH` environment variable ? if yes use `gdb ./myAnalysis`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
gdb ./myAnalysis
```

Also make sure that your other folder isn't in your path. I thought that '.' was implicitly at the head of the search path, but apparently not for all OSes.